# Linux: timeout when opening named pipe for writing

Tags: linux, timeout, named-pipes

I have one process writing to another via a named pipe. It's possible that the reader process will misbehave and not open the pipe for reading. If that happens, my well-behaved writer process will hang on its open() call.
I want the writer to be able to timeout when opening the pipe, so that it may clean up and carry on running if the reader hasn't opened its end in time. Nonblocking open() immediately returns error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is an option, use unix domain sockets for a scenario like this.  Due to the semantics of FIFOs this is an awkward way to do this and you are likely going to run into problems past the open anyway.  And this design won't scale beyond one client if that becomes necessary.  You may be able to enforce your will on the FIFOs in the short term but I suspect you will come to regret it.

Sockets are a much more natural fit for this.  Your listening socket fits nicely into your existing poll(), client connects, writer dumps his data, both ends disconnect, and everybody is happy.  No fuss, no muss.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid having to set up sockets but your points are absolutely valid.

Answer (score 0):

In your writer process open the pipe in read-write mode, that should prevent it from hanging :)

Comment: If I do that, how can I tell when the other process has opened for reading?

Comment: What error does the nonblocking open return ? Did you try nonblocking mode with the read-write mode ? You should be able to test (using select or poll) if the pipe is ready for writing - if it is it means that the client has connected to the other end.

Comment: poll() returns writable immediately if I've opened it in RW mode, even if the other end hasn't yet been opened.